# Do wheels travel slower when rolling compared to sliding?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, gravity, friction, angular-velocity

If we have a wheel rolling down a hill with some amount of friction that causes angular motion and an ice cube that slides down the hill with no friction with the surface, which one accelerates/travels faster?

Assume again that the same wheel is rolling down the hill with a very small amount of angular motion. Now, is it still slower that the ice cube?

Comment: If all the energy is coming from gravity then this is the same input for both, think about where the energy goes = kinetic + other. Which has most 'other'

Comment: The object with less rotational energy will travel faster ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this problem can be analyzed with forces and torques, it's really a situation for global principles: conservation of energy.

You don't even need the details. If your mass $m$ falls some height $h$, the available gravitational potential energy is $U$.

That means the translational K.E. is:

$$ T_T = \frac 1 2 m v^2 = U $$

Now if it rolls too:

$$ T_T' + T_R = \frac 1 2 m v'^2 + \frac 1 2 I \omega^2 = U $$

From that, you should be able to convince yourself that:

$$ v > v'$$

Another technique for qualitative answers is to look at an extreme case. Imagine you wheel is a disk with 2 masses, $m$, on opposing sides of a diameter.

If it slides at speed $v$, the kinetic energy computed by summing over
the 2 masses:

$$T = \frac 1 2 mv^2 + \frac 1 2 mv^2 = mv^2$$

Meanwhile, if it rolls, there's a point (vertical alignment) where:

$$ T = \frac 1 2 m (0\cdot v)^2 + \frac 1 2 m (2\cdot v)^2 = 2mv^2 $$

so that the rolling speed is less than the sliding speed.

Answer (score 2):

When something rolls, it possesses both rotational Kinetic energy $K_r$ and translational Kinetic energy $K_t$. This means that a portion of the initial mechanical energy $M$ is transferred to  $K_r$ rather than all being converted to $K_t$.

(Explanation derived from conservation of energy): $$M = U_{gi} = K_{rf} +K_{tf}$$

This results in a rotating object of the same initial height to travel slower down a ramp than a sliding object (with negligible friction).

Assuming your second wheel has a small but non-negligible amount of $K_r$, it still will reach the bottom of the ramp after the sliding ice cube.

The only way the wheel would reach the bottom at the same time as the ice cube is if there is no friction acting on the wheel. With no frictional force, no net torque is acting on the wheel and it will (counterintuitively) slide down the ramp next to the ice cube without rotating.